# how can i get the max memory usage of a child process after its execution accurately?

Tags: linux

I have written a program which is used to monitoring child processes' resources. I used wait4 function's fourth argument to get child processes' CPU usage, which works fine. But i could use that to get memory usage, it looks different from the output of "ps". I also tried parsing /proc/pid/status, but sometimes it's not accurate, for some child process is too quick to parse. can anybody give me some advice or solution? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Once the process terminates, even though the process entry still exists in the kernel, all of the resources for the process are released by the kernel.  So, I would not expect to be able to read the memory size of the process from /proc.

In addition, there's no "maximum memory used" statistic for the process.

The only ways I can think to determine the maximum amount of memory for a process are the following:

1. Periodically sample the process state while it's executing and grab the current memory usage,
2. Use `strace` to capture all of the system calls made by the process and process this to determine just how much memory the process used, or
3. Use a shared library to intercept the memory-allocation system calls as they are made by the process, capture the details, and find a way to report

I would probably go with (1) unless very high accuracy is absolutely needed.

There may be profiling or statistics tools to help in this task, but I'm not aware of any.

---

### Using Strace

Here's a program that illustrates the use of `strace` for this purpose:

**allocit.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
        int     cur;

        cur = 0;
        while ( cur < 1000 )
        {
                malloc(1024);
                cur++;
        }

        return  0;
}
```

Running this with strace (`strace ./allocit`) gets output like this:

```
execve("./allocit", ["./allocit"], [/* 49 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1b991000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2ae49dccd000
uname({sys="Linux", node="fearless.office.tmcs", ...}) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/jdoe/lib/tls/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/jdoe/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff896b2900) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/jdoe/lib/tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/jdoe/lib/tls", 0x7fff896b2900) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/jdoe/lib/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/jdoe/lib/x86_64", 0x7fff896b2900) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/jdoe/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/jdoe/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/software/ticketmaster/lib/tls/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/software/ticketmaster/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff896b2900) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/software/ticketmaster/lib/tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/software/ticketmaster/lib/tls", 0x7fff896b2900) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/software/ticketmaster/lib/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/software/ticketmaster/lib/x86_64", 0x7fff896b2900) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/software/ticketmaster/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/software/ticketmaster/lib", 0x7fff896b2900) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/tls/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/tls/x86_64", 0x7fff896b2900) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/tls/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/tls", 0x7fff896b2900) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/x86_64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/x86_64", 0x7fff896b2900) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=123338, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 123338, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x2ae49dcce000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)      = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\332!\2359\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1717800, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2ae49dced000
mmap(0x399d200000, 3498328, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x399d200000
mprotect(0x399d34e000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x399d54d000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x14d000) = 0x399d54d000
mmap(0x399d552000, 16728, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x399d552000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x2ae49dcee000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x2ae49dcee210) = 0
mprotect(0x399d54d000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x399d01b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x2ae49dcce000, 123338)          = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x1b991000
brk(0x1b9b2000)                         = 0x1b9b2000
brk(0x1b9d3000)                         = 0x1b9d3000
brk(0x1b9f4000)                         = 0x1b9f4000
brk(0x1ba15000)                         = 0x1ba15000
brk(0x1ba36000)                         = 0x1ba36000
brk(0x1ba57000)                         = 0x1ba57000
brk(0x1ba78000)                         = 0x1ba78000
brk(0x1ba99000)                         = 0x1ba99000
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

Note all of the `brk()` calls used to expand the heap.

Comment: And you can sample the process state by reading `/proc/$PID/statm` or `/proc/$PID/status`

Comment: I just tried (2), i found out that (2) could't trace the allocation of    global variables. I have a thought that compiler did the allocation job of global variables before execution.

Comment: @zxjcarrot - the allocation of global variables is internal to the process.  Processes grab memory from the O/S (via requests to the kernel) in large chunks, then tools like `malloc` and `new` allocate from that pool, adding more from the O/S as needed.  The system calls that I know are involved are `brk()` and `sbrk()`.

Comment: Correction - `sbrk` is not a system call (as per the man page).  It calls `brk` to perform it's task.

Comment: Thank you guys, i've solved this problem by monitoring child process function exit() using ptrace. When child process call the exit, it will be stopped and send parent a signal, then i parse the /proc file.